# Use different models for deserialization in retrofit success and error callbacks

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

The API I am working with gives completely different responses for success and failure.

Success:

```
{
   "token":"asdfasdfhkAADBSKJBJBJKBJBK^%&BJBLLKHKJBXZ",
   "email":"sample@sample.com",
   "role":"admin"
}
```

Failure:

```
{
   "name": "NotAuthenticated",
   "message": "Invalid login.",
   "code": 401,
   "className": "not-authenticated"
}
```

I am very new to retrofit and am using the below code to make the call.

```
LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest(mobileNumber, password);
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.authenticateUser(request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

As you can see, retrofit forces me to use the Sample `ResponseObject` for both `success` and `failure`. And hence I am not able to convert the failure response to a pojo.

I have looked at custom deserialization. But writing a custom deserializer for each request can quickly go out of control.

Please help out.

Comment: you are looking for `errorBody` I think

Comment: I am guessing _failure_ returns also 200 OK?

Comment: nope, all failure response return error codes between 400 - 499.

Comment: But as already mentioned your error body would then be in `Response.errorBody` and would not interfere with your success case, enabling you to have different data types. You still have to deserialize the error body though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for this will be getting Response Body form retrofit and Serializing it by our self in GSON . I am also looking for other sort of solution.